# HTML Multi Select attribute not working on mobile browsers

Tags: html, forms, select, mobile, responsive-design

I'm looking for a solution for a mobile website version with multiple selects in a search form using the most simple HTML code and I can't use jQuery Mobile ;(

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="New York">New York</option>
  <option value="Londres">Londres</option>
  <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
  <option value="Zurich">Zurich</option>
</select>
```

[Here is the JSFiddle to see it on desktop!](http://jsfiddle.net/8sqRJ/)

In this form, the user will select more than one option, but this code is not working perfectly on mobile browsers (except on Windows Mobile). It's loosing some selected options after I close the select box.

Thanks!

Comment: If I emulate an iphone with google chrome, it works. but where do you send the selected options. Can you use normal jQuery?

Comment: See this fiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/danielgasser/dZ9TZ/